# Selecting an intersection with a fixed given percentage between two tables

Tags: postgresql

I working with PostgreSQL and I have two tables:

#### Serieses

```
SeriesID
716
718
214
210
```

#### Viewers

```
ViewID    SeriesID
10          716
12          718
10          718
15          770
10          210
12          214
12          210
```

How can I create a query which for each viewer if it has series intersection more than 70% with table serieses I add it to the final result?

In our example we will get:

#### Result:

```
ViewerID
10
12
```

Comment: And don't forget version!  Take a look [here](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example) and [here](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql). Give us DDL and DML, some sample data in a fiddle and your desired result. p.s. welcome to the forum!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following:

Created the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE my_series 
(
  series_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE viewer 
(
  view_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  series_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT viewer_pk PRIMARY KEY (view_id, series_id)
);
```

Input your sample data:

```
INSERT INTO my_series VALUES (210), (214), (716), (718), (770);
INSERT INTO viewer VALUES (10, 210), (10, 716), (10, 718), (12, 210), (12, 214), (12, 718);
```

Ran the following query:

```
SELECT v.view_id, COUNT(v.view_id) AS "View count"
FROM viewer v
GROUP BY v.view_id
HAVING COUNT(v.series_id) >= 0.70 * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_series) 

-- >= 0.7 * COUNT = a threshold of 70% as per the question
```

Result:

```
view_id View count
     10          3
     12          3
```

All this is available at the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e64368eb27d9be16ee3aed1e873d7bc2)!

For future reference, you are more likely to get better and faster answers if you provide a fiddle. It also reduces the chances of errors (either with data input or answers) on our part and helps reduce duplication of work. These sites are a  great resource and you will get all the more out them if you take the trouble to follow the guidelines.

Comment: can you tell me why 0.50 counts as 0.70 in the context of the requirement  ?

Comment: In the second table you have a ViewerID of 15 and a Series_ID of 770 - I assumed that you wanted 770 in the series table (see fiddle), so the cardinality of the series_id field is now 5 and the count of ViewerID's 10 and 12 is 3. 3/5 = 60% (which is < 75%), so won't appear in a query which looks for 75%!

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding you, actually I don't want the 770 in the result because it does not appear in Serieses table.

can you fix that so I can accept your answer ?

Comment: I'll delete the record in both your post and here - would that be suitable?

Comment: no I need the 770 in the second table. (the first table does not cover all the serieses)

Comment: Done as requested - the extra record in the `viewer` table doesn't affect the result, because we are comparing with the no. of records in the `series` table.

Comment: yes :) , appreciate that

Answer (score 2):

NOT tested in Postgres, but it should be similar to:

```
SELECT V.ViewerID
FROM   Viewers AS V
GROUP BY V.ViewerID
HAVING CAST(COUNT(*) AS NUMERIC) 
       > 
       (0.7 * CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Serieses) AS NUMERIC))
```